# Performing an action when user reassigns an approval step

Tags: approval-process, approval-step, approve-action

In the approval process a user can reassign the step to someone else.
I need to build a business logic around this reassignment but I cannot find where in Salesforce its happening. 
I tried workflows and process builder but these cannot reference the approval process. I tried a trigger but there is no object exposed for the approval step.

Why idea how I can tap into the change (declarative or programmatic)?